# How to build a LambdaExpression from an existing LambdaExpression Without Compiling

Tags: c#, linq, expression, linq-expressions, expressionvisitor

I want to combine two LambdaExpressions without compiling them.

This is what it looks like if I do compile them:

```
    public Expression<Func<TContainer,bool>> CreatePredicate<TContainer,TMember>(
        Expression<Func<TContainer,TMember>> getMemberExpression, 
        Expression<Func<TMember,bool>> memberPredicateExpression)
    {
        return x => memberPredicateExpression.Compile()(getMemberExpression.Compile()(x));
    }
```

That's obviously not the fastest way to get the target expression from the provided arguments.  Also, it makes it incompatible with query providers like LINQ to SQL that do not support C# method calls.

From what I've read it seems like the best approach is to build an `ExpressionVisitor` class.  However, this seems like it could be a pretty common task.  Does anyone know of an existing open source code base that provides this kind of functionality?  If not, what is the best way to approach the `ExpressionVisitor` to make it as generic as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but you could do something like that:

```
public Expression<Func<TContainer,bool>> CreatePredicate<TContainer,TMember>(
    Expression<Func<TContainer,TMember>> getMemberExpression, 
    Expression<Func<TMember,bool>> memberPredicateExpression)
{
    ParameterExpression x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TContainer), "x");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TContainer, bool>>(
        Expression.Invoke(
            memberPredicateExpression,
            Expression.Invoke(
                getMemberExpression,
                x)),
        x);
}
```

Usage:

```
var expr = CreatePredicate(
    (Foo f) => f.Bar,
    bar => bar % 2 == 0);
```

Result:

```
x => Invoke(bar => ((bar % 2) == 0), Invoke(f => f.Bar, x))
```

I guess it would be better to get something like `x => x.Bar % 2 == 0`, but it would probably be significantly harder...

---

EDIT: actually it wasn't so hard with an expression visitor:

```
public Expression<Func<TContainer,bool>> CreatePredicate<TContainer,TMember>(
    Expression<Func<TContainer,TMember>> getMemberExpression, 
    Expression<Func<TMember,bool>> memberPredicateExpression)
{
    return CombineExpressionVisitor.Combine(
        getMemberExpression,
        memberPredicateExpression);
}

class CombineExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression _parameterToReplace;
    private readonly Expression _replacementExpression;
    private CombineExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression parameterToReplace, Expression replacementExpression)
    {
        _parameterToReplace = parameterToReplace;
        _replacementExpression = replacementExpression;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Combine<TSource, TMember, TResult>(
        Expression<Func<TSource, TMember>> memberSelector,
        Expression<Func<TMember, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
         var visitor = new CombineExpressionVisitor(
            resultSelector.Parameters[0],
            memberSelector.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(
            visitor.Visit(resultSelector.Body),
            memberSelector.Parameters);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        if (parameter == _parameterToReplace)
            return _replacementExpression;
        return base.VisitParameter(parameter);
    }
}
```

It gives the following expression:

```
f => ((f.Bar % 2) == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually going for what you said was 'significantly harder'.  This might end up being a good starting point though.

Comment: @Thomas, Okay, this is what I'm thinking: Do what you suggested, but first compare the ParameterExpressions of the LambdaExpression to make sure that there aren't duplicate parameter names.  Then, have an `ExpressionVisitor` visit `ExpressionType.Invoke`, selecting the arguments, and create a new `getMemberExpression.Body`, with the argument values replacing each parameter occurrence.  Then return the LambdaExpression's body.  How does this sound to you?

Comment: @smartcaveman, I eventually wrote an ExpressionVisitor solution, which doesn't need Invoke at all. See my updated answer

Comment: @Thomas, in writing this do you see any potential limitations to its use?

Comment: @smartcaveman, well, as it is now, it only support one parameter... but it could probably be improved to handle several (you would need several overloads of the static `Combine` method of course)