# How do I rewrite query expressions to replace enumerations with ints?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, expression-trees, entity-framework-4.1

Inspired by a desire to be able to use enumerations in EF queries, I'm considering adding an ExpressionVisitor to my repositories that will take incoming criteria/specifications criteria and rewrite them to use the corresponding persisted int property.

I'm consistently using the following Value-suffix pattern in my (code-first) entities:

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    internal int MemberStatusValue { get; set; }

    public MemberStatus MemberStatus 
    {
        get { return (MemberStatus) MemberStatusValue; }
        set { MemberStatusValue = (int) value; }
    }
}
```

And map this to the database using the following:

```
internal class UserMapping : AbstractMappingProvider<User>
{
    public override void DefineModel( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        // adds ToTable and other general mappings
        base.DefineModel( modelBuilder );

        Map.Property( e => e.MemberStatusValue ).HasColumnName( "MemberStatus" );
    }
}
```

In my repositories I have the following method:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query( Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter, params string[] children )
{
    if( children == null || children.Length == 0 )
    {
        return Objects.Where( filter );
    }
    DbQuery<T> query = children.Aggregate<string, DbQuery<T>>( Objects, ( current, child ) => current.Include( child ) );
    return filter != null ? query.Where( filter ) : query;
}
```

I'd like to add a method call inside this method to rewrite the filter expression, replacing all references to the MemberStatus property with references to MemberStatusValue.

I suppose it will be a solution involving something like seen [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361957/how-to-build-a-lambdaexpression-from-an-existing-lambdaexpression-without-compili), but I'm not sure exactly how to get from idea to implementation.

If you can give any advice on the potential performance impact of adding this feature, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://bit.ly/eUOi08

Comment: Thanks, that looks exactly right.. will investigate!

Comment: Also note that the latest version of EF (the June CTP) has native support for enums - and the next official release (4.2) will make it official - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/walkthrough-enums-june-ctp.aspx

Comment: Did it work?  Should any of the above be written up as answers and accepted?

Comment: Yes, but it's not code that I would publish here. Also, EF now has enum support (it just awaits the official 4.5 framework release).

Comment: @StephenMcDaniel looks like you won, if you write it up hopefully Morten will mark it.

Comment: @Joshua I'd actually hesitate to mark an answer that simply said to use EF 4.5 and .NET 4.5, since that is not really what I asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is quite what you're after, but I've found it simpler to handle enums in a similar but slightly different way. To wit, I have two properties, as you do, but my int property is public and is what the database persists; I then have another public "wrapper" property that gets/sets the int property value via casts from/to the desired enumerated type, which is what's actually used by the rest of the application.

As a result, I don't have to mess around with the model; EF understands and persists the int property just fine while the rest of the application gets nice interactions with the enum type. The only thing I don't like about my approach is that I have to write my LINQ statements with a bunch of casts on any enum value I'm trying to query to turn it into an int to match against the field that's actually persisted. It's a small price, however, and I'd like to suggest it to you because it appears to me that you're using a string to generate your query which gives up all the type safety, Intellisense, etc. that LINQ provides.

Finally, if you're interested in a walkthrough of how to use the new enum features in EF 5 (which is available in beta for download now if you'd like to try it out), check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh859576

Comment: Thanks, but you've missed the mark on a few items: I'm not using strings but persisting the int just as you are. The reason for my two properties and the mapping is that I get to map the int value to a column named after the enum property, which should ease the transition to EF5 at some later stage. My queries use int just as yours, but I find it a nuisance to have to use casting - especially as you cannot cast the enum inline in the query, and so must declare a variable for it. The answer I am looking for should provide code to rewrite the query expression graph and do the enum conversions.